# Escaping quotations for jQuery XML request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

Simple question really, I am relatively new to both jQuery and XML.

I just want to pull an email address into a link, but unsure how I am escaping the quotations.

```
<a href="mailto:'+email+'">Email me</a>
```

The +email+ is being taken from an XML file with code like this: `<email>dan@danixd.com</email>`

so I want the HTML to look like:

```
<a href="mailto:dan@danixd.com">Email me</a>
```

Comment: do you mean: `'<a href="mailto:'+email+'">Email me</a>'` ? (looks like you are missing opening and closing quotes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `encodeURIComponent` (just a plain JS function, not related to jQuery):

```
<a href="mailto:'+encodeURIComponent(email)+'">Email me</a>
```